# Wrapping Long Text in a TextBox Control

Tags: .net, winforms

This question is NOT about `WordWrap`.

I have along *Base64* string that users will (probably) paste or (unlikely) enter into a `TextBox` control on my Windows Form.

I want to provide a multi-line `TextBox` so all of the content is visible, BUT I don't want it to be single, long line or to use scroll bars.

Actually, I want it to behave exactly like a `Label` control which, with `WordWrap = False`, wraps any displayed text according to what will fit on each line.

Unfortunately - and I've done a lot of searching - it seems that the Windows Form `TextBox` control doesn't behave this way; you can either `WordWrap` or nothing. And with a *Base64* string with "/" and "+" characters included, this yields a very ugly, non-deterministic appearance.

So, am I left with artificially inserting new line characters in a `TextChanged` event handler and stripping them off later? Or customizing/expanding the `TextBox` control with a `TextWrap` property?

This is quite frustrating. It seems pretty obvious to me at least that this would be a required behavior.

Comment: See [C#: Multiline TextBox with TextBox.WordWrap Displaying Long Base64 String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4576457/719186)

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks for the link. Turns out I have just all of that manual wrapping myself. But I chucked it because it just got more and more complicated, with copying text, cursor management, etc. SmartWrap - huh!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrapping Text in a rich textbox, but not word wrapping it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938998/wrapping-text-in-a-rich-textbox-but-not-word-wrapping-it)

Comment: See proposed duplicate. I don't know if you're using VB.NET or C#, otherwise I'd have just closed this question outright, as the duplicate is exactly the scenario you're asking about. The accepted answer there is almost correct, but not quite so I added a new answer that cleans up the basic approach and fixes one significant bug that exists in the accepted answer.

Comment: Try out this [Justified RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47470191/7444103). Add an empty constructor if you want to drop it from the Toolbox and see that its `SelectionAlignment` property is set to `Justify`.

Answer (score 0):

The Forms TextBox has a property called Multiline. If you set Multiline = True you should get the desired result.

EDIT: I know you said don't say WordWrap, but when I set the TextBox to Multiline = True and also WordWrap = True it is behaving the same as a label in all my test cases.

This is in Visual Studio 2017, Targeting .NET 4.7.2. I create a new Forms app. Added a TextBox and a Label. I set them to the same size. I pasted in

VGhlIHF1aWNrIGJyb3duIGZveCBqdW1wZWQgb3ZlciB0aGUgbGF6eSBkb2dzLiAxMjM0NTY3ODkw LT0hQCMkJV4mKigpXytbXVw7

to the Text properties on both controls. I set the TextBox to multiline = True and WordWrap = True and this was the result. If this is not what you're looking for please add a picture of what you're expecting.

[image]

Comment: Nope. You need `Multiline` to get a vertically-sizeable `TextBox` but it doesn't split the text on the right-hand extent. Try it. Or check the other posts here on the topic (without a solution).

Comment: I must not understand what you're trying to accomplish then, because when I created a label and a multiline textbox they both wrapped exactly the same.

Comment: I can't easily post a screenshot, but I definitely don't get that result. Are you entering a continuous string longer than the width of the `TextBox`? If you have spaces and `WordWrap` on, it will wrap. Only the `Label` wraps on text hitting the right-hand extent.

Comment: Yes I have 1 continuous block of base64 text. I pasted it into the textbox and the label where both are the exact same size and the text is identical in both. VGhlIHF1aWNrIGJyb3duIGZveCBqdW1wZWQgb3ZlciB0aGUgbGF6eSBkb2dzLiAxMjM0NTY3ODkw
LT0hQCMkJV4mKigpXytbXVw7JywuL3t9fDoiPD4/

Comment: Well, I'm stunned because I cannot get that result. Can you please post an answer with a screenshot rather than continue in comments? Please include details of the test project, .NET version, etc. I have two projects that behave exactly the same and are consistent with other Q&A I've seen here and elsewhere.

Comment: I added details to my answer. Please explain how this differs from what you're requesting.

Comment: I think I see the issue. My Base64 text uses / and + characters (pretty common). I'm finding that the sequences "+{0-9}" or "{0-9}+" (eg "+2", "6+") cause a line break. Can you try that? Note: This only happens in some positions in the text!

Comment: Yes, +2 does seem to force a line break.

Comment: Can anyone explain this? Is it interpreting "+{0-9}" as an equation?? it's giving me all kinds of headaches. @bwing I removed the down vote; your answer is fair enough under the circumstances!

Comment: I'll do some digging and see what I can find. It appears that any special character followed by a number causes this. (2  and /2 also cause the line break.

Comment: I couldn't replicate with "/{0-9}" but I believe you. Somewhere I saw it called "SmartWrap"!!! Yeah, no.